# What buff is this orange symbol icon?

Tags: path-of-exile

Does anyone knows what buff is that from the screenshot that character's top orange symbol icon?

[image]

Comment: Buffs and curses will appear in the top left of your screen, you can mouse over it to read it's description. Though I advice against doing that in the middle of a fight... I am not very familiar with visual effects of curses but that looks like flammability, which reduces fire resistance and increase burn damage receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orange lady above the character's head signals that a flask with the suffix "of Warding" is currently active, which makes your character immune to curses during the effect, see **[wikia entry](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_flask_suffix_mods)**.

The symbol for this buff is the purple picture showing the figure with the X above it's head, as seen in the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

That's not a buff but the Silence curse, which makes your character unable to cast spells.

An higher quality image to show how it looks like on your character:
[image]